# why is UIFont.LineHeight read-only?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uifont

Any idea how to set line height in MonoTouch?

`UIFont.LineHeight` is read-only and has got no setter.

MonoTouch: 6.0.8

Answer (score 2):

It's an Objective-C `readonly` property, see Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIFont/lineHeight).

What you need to do is create a new `UIFont` instance, with a size that will match the line height you want, and assign (or use) that font instance in your code.

Comment: sorry, can please explain, maybe some sample code. I tried to create a new instance of UIFont but not sure how to set the size tho? Frame does not affect the line height

Comment: @PaulMieczkowski the point is, that you don't just mutate it, you create a new one. The instance that you have got - it would've been created with some lineHeight implied/deducted from font source file/specified in the constructor. Creating a font with different one requires you to modify this initial creation.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I needed to change line spacing, but keep font size. Maybe [this solution](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=22374) is a dirty hack, but it is simpler than writing your own UI components or use third-party libraries.